# Logic Apps Switch Subscription

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-logic-apps

I'm currently working with Logic Apps in the designer in VS 2017 in the context of one subscription. How do I switch to another subscription? I can't seem to find where the option is?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Within VS2017 you should be able to do this from the cloud explorer. If only one subscription is showing, click on Account Management (the person icon) and make sure all subscriptions are ticked. If there's only one subscription available then make sure you're not logged in with your personal account, if the subscriptions are on the work account

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to switch the subscription using VS2017. If you want to do switch the resource to another subscription, you can directly use Azure portal or In VS2017 cloud explorer, right-click on the logic app which you want to switch. Click on 'Open in Portal'. It will navigate you to azure portal, there you can see the option to change subscription near subscription field.

[image: switch_subscription]